# Casing strategy on custom serializer is not picked up by linq provider

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We need properties on a document that are polymorphic, so to enable this, we use a custom CosmosSerializer implementation that uses TypeHandling.Auto of Newtonsoft.Json. This works fine - actually, this serializer is an internal class in the Cosmos SDK, internal to "easy" the migration towards System.Text.Json.

Unfortunately, as we are using camel casing in the serialization towards the documents, things go wrong when using an item queryable, as the linq provider does not seem to "respect" the serialization setup, and the query is using capital casing which leads to results that are always empty.

When setting up the camel casing with CosmosSerializationOptions, this is not the case. So clearly the usage of the custom serializer is the cause of this issue.

Is anyone aware of a solution to this problem? Google tells me that I should decorate the properties used in linq queries with JsonProperty attributes, but they are not picked up it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in the end, the solution is to add a CosmosLinqSerializerOptions while requesting an ItemLinqQueryable from the container, which allows you to specify the naming policy as well.